# Pandas aggregate ordered point coordinates

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas series of ordered point coordinates:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d=pd.Series([(1,1),(2,2),(3,4),(4,6)])
>>> d
0    (1, 1)
1    (2, 2)
2    (3, 4)
3    (4, 6)
dtype: object
>>>
```

I want to create a series of the line segments formed by these points. In this case there would be 3 line segments (between point 0 and 1, 1 and 2, and 2 and 3.

I can create that below by concatenating the original series with the "shifted" version of it, getting rid of the first null value, and then applying a function to the two columns.

```
>>> pd.concat([d.shift(),d],1).dropna().apply(lambda x:tuple([x[0], x[1]]),1)
1    ((1, 1), (2, 2))
2    ((2, 2), (3, 4))
3    ((3, 4), (4, 6))
dtype: object
>>>
```

Is there a better approach to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like using `zip` for this

```
pd.Series(list(zip(d.values[:-1], d.values[1:])))

0    ((1, 1), (2, 2))
1    ((2, 2), (3, 4))
2    ((3, 4), (4, 6))
dtype: object
```

Comment: very nice solution.

Comment: @jezrael tyvm :-)

Comment: Nice. Since `zip` cuts off once the shortest iterable is exhausted, you could save a few characters by making the first entry just `d`.  It's a little less explicit though.